# Windows: Are there any examples of applications that can be cleanly uninstalled while an instance of it is running?

Tags: java, installation, uninstallation, windows

The firm I work for, has a Java based tool, that runs on both Linux and Windows. One of the testcases for Windows platform involved uninstalling and installing the tool while an instance of it is running. I pointed out that a clean uninstall or install in this case will not happen, and the test case is bound to fail, since for any Windows application, if we try to uninstall it while it is running, it will protest.

One of my seniors pointed out that the above is not necessarily true and that depends on the design of the application. I was not entirely convinced and checked on Internet, but couldn't find anything to support his claim.

Can anyone give me examples of applications which can be uninstalled while an instance of it is running, for Windows? Or which have silent uninstallation, for that matter? Are there any examples of applications where a clean uninstall/install takes place despite an instance of the application is running?

Just curious to know if that is actually possible.

Comment: It can be done, but it's dirty.  Basically, you would have "launcher" which would copy the "core" application to "running" location and would then execute this "core" via the command line (`javaw.exe` works well), allowing the launcher to terminate.  You could then update the application while the instance was running...switching instances is another issue, but not insurmountable...

Comment: I believe it's possible to terminate the running instance on uninstall, that should take care of the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what is my understanding as well @ElliottFrisch . The running instance must be terminated to get a clean uninstall/install.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I didn't quite understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Basically, you have a Jar/program, which, when executed, copies the "core application" to another "running" location and then executes in some which which would allow the Jar/program to terminate after the "core application" is running.  This would allow the "existing" install base to be removed and update without issue. You would simply need to be able to tell the running instance to terminate, which can be achieved through the use of sockets...or files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some pointers:**

You can use below command to kill a process forcefully:

```
taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe
```

**Java code:**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe")
```

If you use `Runtime.exec()` to start a process through java, then using valid `Process` reference you can invoke `destroy()` method to kill process.

**Regarding your issue:**

You can simply call uninstall.exe of respective program like:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Your Program\\uninstall\\remove.exe").start();
```

**Note:**

Make sure you are killing the running instance(s) of the program before you uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what is my understanding of it, the running instances must be killed to get a clean install/uninstall .

Comment: You are right, if this is not done, then uninstall process will not be successful.